# disable printWidth on prettier

Tags: prettier

Is there a way to disable the **printWidth** rule warning in prettier?

I want to be able to determine my own line length for readability. In certain cases I want a line break, and in other cases I don't.

I tried this in my .prettierrc file :

```
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "printWidth" : "off"
}
```

But this does not work.

Answer (score 27):

The short answer is no, you cannot disable it entirely.

There are, however, a few workarounds, but they have caveats.

To quote an answer from this issue on github: https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/3468.
printWidth is not a rule but an input into the algorithm they use to generate their output. Meaning, it is required to be there.

One workaround is to set printWidth to a really high number, but although this will prevent lines from breaking, changing this property will affect your entire codebase, causing other lines throughout it to combine into a single line, which is most likely not desired.

Your second option is to disable prettier for a block of code with the `// prettier-ignore` syntax. The downside to this is that you'll disable all prettier features for this section of the code. Also, I personally don't find it very "clean" to have comments like that all over your code.
You can read about how to use the ignore functionality here: https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html

Comment: This tool should be called `uglier`.

Comment: `printWidth: Infinity` works for me.

Comment: Just be aware that sometimes multiple lines will be combined into a single line which might not be desired. Unfortunately, I don't have an example at hand, but I've seen lines multiple screen widths wide. Might be fixed in newer versions of course.

Comment: it's the worst feature I have seen. it forces you to ugly your code.

Comment: Sometimes I really wanna put my fn args on multi-lines for more readability. Sometimes I don't want my team members to focus on a function, so readable in this case is put all of args in 1 single line. low printWidth will force all fn to put their args on multiple lines, high printWidth will force all fn to put their args on 1 line. That's right it's UGLIER. because of super opinionated lib orientation

Comment: Because of this limitation only our company will stop using prettier as the formatting tool. The amount of conflict resulting from this single configuration resulted in production bugs and days of testing and searching for code that basically disappeared. It's unacceptable for bugs to appear from the use of a formatting tool.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable prettier rules once,  just do:

```
// prettier-ignore
const date = new Date()   // prettier disabled on this line
```

Comment: @OliverWatkins Oliver is right, his code would not be, "prettier", It would be "uglier" instead. This option defeats the entire point of using a formatting tool. IMO this is not just a bad solution, but it really isn't a solution at all, as it doesn't disable the rule, it just disables prettier entirely for 1 line. What he suppose to do put this on every line?

Comment: Human always formats the code better then a simple code. With no exceptions. So if you use "prettyfier" you will always end up with less readable code. imho these kind of tools should only make sure semicolons are there as expected etc and not to touch the code formatting at all.

Answer (score 0):

If it's your JS code.
There was a hacky solution: add comment `//` to your end of line, so no one can append your code into the comment right?

As a result the fn in the example will have args on 2 separate lines:

Eg:

```
function lorem(
  foo: string, //
  bar: number, //
) {
  ...
}
```

On the the side, in case you want it on a single line? It's default behavior because of `printWidth`