# Disable any changes or checking on line width in Prettier and ESLint

Tags: eslint, prettier, eslintrc

I've got a project and the auto-format on line width is driving me insane. I tried setting it to `999` characters as some recommended, but then it FORCES all of my lines that I want to be broken up into one line.

---

I set `"printWidth": 999` in my `.prettierrc` and I set `'max-len': 'off'` in `.eslintrc.cjs` and it now formats long lines in one line but it

1. Still yells at me saying to replace the spaces with newlines (`eslint(prettier/prettier)`) and
2. If I want to make a new line it forces me to put it back to one when I format...

How can I tell ESLint and Prettier to just leave me alone in terms of line length?

---

I don't want my lines forcibly reformatted and always underlined in red or orange. Also setting print width to `Infinity` and `false` does not work.

---

Related questions:

[ESLint / Prettier -- enforce max-len / printWidth, but don't require it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63419894/eslint-prettier-enforce-max-len-printwidth-but-dont-require-it)

[disable printWidth on prettier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54325979/disable-printwidth-on-prettier)

https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/3468

https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html

[How to disable eslint rule max line length for paragraph in <template> of vue.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468673/how-to-disable-eslint-rule-max-line-length-for-paragraph-in-template-of-vue-js) (I'm not using Vue but still)

Comment: I think the cores problem are 1) that even though `max-len` is set to off in my eslint config, it STILL underlines in red 2) prettier still formats my lines because it doesn't like the line length

Comment: You can't. You can turn off rules in ESLint, but Prettier is a lot more opinionated - the point is not to spend time thinking about layout, if you want your code "just so", _don't use it_.

Comment: So there's no way to turn off the line length rule / formatting? I'm fine with it being opinionated, but just this one thing I want to not be forced on me.